# PyQt : data is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, python-2.7, pyqt4, qstring

I am new to PyQt GUI. I want to get the data of a `QLineEdit` text box, and for that I am using the `text()` method. I am getting the data, but the data type is a `QString`. I need to transmit this as json data to a server, and for that I am using the `json.dumps()` method - but I get an error.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image
import json

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class stackedExample(QWidget):

   def __init__(self):
      super(stackedExample, self).__init__()
      self.current_module = 'GUI'
      print (self.current_module)

      self.takeFinger = False

      self.personaldata = None
      self.vehicledata = None

      self.leftlist = QListWidget ()
      self.leftlist.insertItem (0, 'Personal Info' )

      self.stack1 = QWidget()

      self.stack1UI()

      self.Stack = QStackedWidget (self)
      self.Stack.addWidget (self.stack1)

      hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
      hbox.addWidget(self.leftlist)
      hbox.addWidget(self.Stack)

      self.setLayout(hbox)
      self.leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)
      self.setGeometry(450, 120, 30,30)

      self.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
      print "2"

   def stack1UI(self):
      layout = QFormLayout()
      self.s1 = QLabel("System ID")
      self.s1_val = QLineEdit()
      layout.addRow(self.s1,self.s1_val)
      self.s2 = QLabel("Driver Name")
      self.s2_val = QLineEdit()
      layout.addRow(self.s2,self.s2_val)
      self.s3 = QLabel("Aadhar ID")
      self.s3_val = QLineEdit()
      layout.addRow(self.s3,self.s3_val)

      self.s4 = QLabel("Driver Phone")
      self.s4_val = QLineEdit()
      layout.addRow(self.s4,self.s4_val)

      self.s5 = QLabel("Age")
      self.s5_val = QLineEdit()
      layout.addRow(self.s5,self.s5_val)

      sex = QHBoxLayout()
      sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Male"))
      sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("Female"))
      layout.addRow(QLabel("Sex"),sex)
      self.b4 = QPushButton("&Save")
      self.b4.setDefault(True)
      self.b4.clicked.connect(self.personalData)
      layout.addWidget(self.b4)
      self.stack1.setLayout(layout)

   def personalData(self):
      print (self.s1_val.toPlainText())
      print type(self.s1_val.text())
      if (self.s1_val.text().isEmpty()):
         print "s1 is empty"
         #self.popup_window()
      if (self.s2_val.text().isEmpty()):
         print "s2 is empty"
      if (self.s3_val.text().isEmpty()):
         print "s3 is empty"
      if (self.s4_val.text().isEmpty()):
         print "s4 is empty"
      if (self.s5_val.text().isEmpty()):
         print "s5 is empty"

      if(not self.s1_val.text().isEmpty() and not self.s2_val.text().isEmpty()):
         #Data1 = {'systemID':self.s1_val.text(),'driverName': self.s2_val.text(),'aadharID': self.s3_val.text(),'driverPhone': self.s4_val.text(),'Age': self.s5_val.text()}
         Data1 = {'systemID': self.s1_val.toPlainText()}
         self.personaldata = json.dumps(self.s1_val.text())
         print ("personal json ready")

   def display(self,i):
      self.Stack.setCurrentIndex(i)

   def on_takephoto(self):
      self.showImage('photo.jpg')
   def getFinger(self):
      return self.takeFinger 
   def setFinger(self):
      self.takeFinger = True
```

The error is:

```
    <class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hearthacker/Desktop/gui code sagar/stacked.py", line 138, in personalData
        self.personaldata = json.dumps(self.s1_val.text())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
        return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
        raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
    TypeError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u's') is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: how about a traceback?

Comment: i am submitting a form. when i click on save button, i have to get the data from all edit box for that  i called Personaldata() function. when i pass it  into json.dumps() method. I got the error..

Comment: @Himanshumittal What is the data that you place on your form?

Comment: I am placing random data..like in error you can see a character "s" is there and next line shows its data type which is a class

Comment: You got a QString where you should have a `str`. Since you are also working with Python 2.7 the problem might be that you use unicode as text input? So either surround your .text() calls with str(..) or read more about it ([some documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html?highlight=qstring)) or use Python 3 and PyQt5 (which definitely do not have that problem).

Comment: Thanks you.. I got it

Answer (score 3):

If you use PyQt5, or Python3 with PyQt4, you will not get this kind of error, because PyQt will always return ordinary Python types whenever possible. But you are using Python2 with PyQt4, which means you have to explicitly request that behaviour.

To do that, change your imports as follows:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

(And note that the `setapi` calls *must* go before the first import of any PyQt modules in your application).

With that in place, you will also need to simplify your code to this:

```
   def personalData(self):
      print type(self.s1_val.text())
      if not self.s1_val.text():
         print "s1 is empty"
         #self.popup_window()
      if not self.s2_val.text():
         print "s2 is empty"
      if not self.s3_val.text():
         print "s3 is empty"
      if not self.s4_val.text():
         print "s4 is empty"
      if not self.s5_val.text():
         print "s5 is empty"

      if self.s1_val.text() and self.s2_val.text():
         Data1 = {'systemID': self.s1_val.text()}
         self.personaldata = json.dumps(Data1)
         print ("personal json ready")
```

PS:

If you're just starting out learning Python and/or PyQt, I would strongly recommend that you use Python3 and PyQt5 if at all possible.